# Trouble serializing payload with ES256 with JWS

Tags: php, jwt

Here is my current code.

```
use Jose\Component\Core\AlgorithmManager;
use Jose\Component\Core\JWK;
use Jose\Component\Signature\Algorithm\ES256;
use Jose\Component\Signature\JWSBuilder;
$algorithm_manager = new AlgorithmManager([
    new ES256(),
]);
$header = array("zip" => "DEF","alg" => "ES256","kid" => "...kid...");
$payload = array("info...");
$js = json_encode($payload,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$jwk = new JWK([
    'kty' => 'ES256',
    'k' => '...kid...',
]);
$jwsBuilder = new JWSBuilder($algorithm_manager);
$jws = $jwsBuilder
    ->create()                               // We want to create a new JWS
    ->withPayload($js)                  // We set the payload
    ->addSignature($jwk, ['alg' => 'ES256']) // We add a signature with a simple protected header
    ->build(); 

$serializer = new CompactSerializer(); // The serializer

$token = $serializer->serialize($jws, 0); // We serialize the signature at index 0 (we only have one signature).
```

Whenever I try to serialize this it tells me this error.

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Wrong key type. in vendor/web-token/jwt-framework/src/SignatureAlgorithm/ECDSA/ECDSA.php:72

This is the first time i'm using this software so i may be forgetting a step or something.

Would some one be so kind as to point me to where im going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of notes

1. ES256 is an asymmetric algorithm that requires an `EC` (elliptic curve) P-256 curve (`crv`) key. You're currently passing, well, for a lack of better word - nonsense - `k` in JWK is "Key Value" of a symmetric ("kty":"oct") secret.
2. "zip": "DEF" is a JWE header that has no place or use in a JWS.

For 1) pass a private P-256 EC key, for 2) get rid of this header.

An example P-256 private key in JWK format looks like this

```js
{
  kty: 'EC',
  x: 'WoOQG8MYKVOUIOj3Ps1r_2qpQyPIef9MC9due2kJJZU',
  y: 'uLci-1X5VlGCo9-Pei7fBk5W9R8Gw8nEUHoUmf-tJIg',
  crv: 'P-256',
  d: 'Ma-sIY1NsqaISoDUyCTDp2PMuuA42Yb3I2Wcp4QLRDE'
}
```

It's public JWK form (for verification) is

```js
{
  kty: 'EC',
  x: 'WoOQG8MYKVOUIOj3Ps1r_2qpQyPIef9MC9due2kJJZU',
  y: 'uLci-1X5VlGCo9-Pei7fBk5W9R8Gw8nEUHoUmf-tJIg',
  crv: 'P-256'
}
```

Comment: what are the x and y for? just different signatures?

Comment: They are the x and y coordinates of an elliptic curve point.

Comment: i was able to generate the string, then serialize it. but this one was 4211 characters. a known original serialized string was 1881. Is there a reason why this way is dramatically longer? Im asking as im having trouble making a qrcode.

I also got this error when trying to unserialize.

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unsupported input

Comment: Hard to comment without context.

Comment: sorry. here check this out. https://pastebin.com/EiHZpbTh ...The decode from an shc qrcode works flawlessly. but when i try to encode a payload and then serialize it its much longer. I then realized that i have to deflate the payload to compress it and then it can fit on the qrcode. I cant deflate it though because it wont accept anythign outside of utf-8

Comment: The encoded header and signature alone is 194 bytes. The rest is your serialized JWS payload.

Comment: final question, how do you compress or deflate when the only acceptable input is utf-8? this is a jw string i refer to as the payload being deflated. https://pastebin.com/55newxZQ <-- check this out for the string and then check the payload. this payload is deflated. and if you check the code i have to inflate it before its even readable. How can i have the payload deflate and then serialize it.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that "zip":"DEF" is not valid for JWS (but the library handles it anyway). The token's payload you've pasted is already deflated so it seems like your job is done.

Comment: that string i sent you was a working and valid jw i was suppose to work with.

I still need to deflate my payload in order for it to not be readable but also to shorten the data being sent.the company app will not show it to be valid until i can defalte it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241496/discussion-between-filip-skokan-and-derek-hill).